# Why does a non-daemon thread running an infinite loop stop?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

As we know the JVM will stop if all non-daemon threads exit, and if a non-daemon thread doesn't exit, the JVM won't exit. However, when I run the code below, the result seems different than I expected.

```
public class Test{

public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("start");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true){
                System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " - running");
            }
        }
    }).start();

    System.out.println("end");
    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("inter");
    }
    }
}
```

I think that what should happen is that the JVM shouldn't exit and will output `running` forever, but after 1 second the output stops. Why does this happen? Is my comprehension wrong or my is my Test class not suitable?

update: I have try the command `ps | grep java`,but no result,
And when I remove `sleep(1000)` `running` will be printed out forever,I'm using mac and java 1.8,anyone can tell me why this happens,thanks!
[image]

Comment: I can not reproduce this behaviour and have infinite output. Which java version do you use?

Comment: How do you run the program? Are you sure it exits? It may be that your console gets overloaded with all your "running" printing...

Comment: you can see if the jvm process is there using `ps | grep java` or using the task manager or whatever. so see if it's there, you don't need to rely on console output. also realize "end" will likely print before your new thread starts printing.

Comment: But you didn't set it as a Daemon thread before starting it. User thread is the default you're starting from and the new anonymous thread is inheriting it.

Comment: @coladict: i think what the OP is alleging is that a non-daemon thread is not sufficient to keep the jvm alive, which conflicts with what I've observed, and using console output for evidence here is not reliable. the console can handle only so much output and writing to stdout without any letup is overwhelming it, is anybody surprised there's a cutoff where the console says enough already? sleep once in a while, like Peter Lawrey's example.

Comment: I run this with javac and java commands in command console.

Comment: anyone,I have post my screencap of executing commands,anyone can provide my a solution?

Comment: Your output doesn't match your program. Can you post the program you are actually running?

Comment: Can you remove the `sleep(1000);` at the end so we can see where you print `end`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey,unbelievable,when I remove `sleep(1000)` as you said,The loop will run at all.why this?

Comment: @PeterLawrey,sorry,I have updated the code in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("start");

        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " - running");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("end");
    }
}
```

I get

```
start
2016-01-15T08:30:58.378 - running
2016-01-15T08:30:58.889 - running
end
2016-01-15T08:30:59.389 - running
2016-01-15T08:30:59.890 - running
2016-01-15T08:31:00.391 - running
2016-01-15T08:31:00.892 - running
2016-01-15T08:31:01.392 - running
2016-01-15T08:31:01.893 - running
2016-01-15T08:31:02.394 - running
... many more
```

Comment: I have tried again,the sam result as my question,but I found when I remove sleep(1000) ,The loop will run forever,why this? I'm running this code on mac and java 1.8

Comment: @FireSun The sleep shouldn't make any difference except cause the thread to sleep for 1000 ms.

Comment: Then I'm really confused why my problem happens?

Comment: I tried on other platform and find this is mac problem.thanks.